# SQSPolicy Fails during stack creation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs

I can't seem to figure out what is causing this failure. I referred to one [article](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=132264). Can anyone tell me what may be causing this error?

```yaml
AllowSNS2SQSPolicy:
    Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
    Properties:
      Queues: [ !Ref SQSQueue ]
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Id: SQSPolicy
        Statement: 
        - Sid: Allow-SNS-SendMessage    
          Effect: Allow 
          Principal:    
            AWS:
            - 'arn:aws:ecs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId:}:cluster/foo'
          Action:   
          - 'sqs:SendMessage'
          - 'sqs:ReceiveMessage' 
        Resource: !GetAtt [SQSQueue, Arn]
```

Error Message:

> Invalid value for parameter Policy. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 400, Error Code: InvalidAttributeValue...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your ECS cluster as Principal?

Comment: I am trying to make it so the ECS cluster can access the Sqs queue

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you've resolved the issue or not, but maybe this'll help someone else.

I had this issue and just got it resolved by allowing any user to access the resource. I don't know why, but I couldn't get Json Policies to work when a `Principal` is specified? Neither I found any examples that would use anything but `Principal: "*"` ...

Even if you allow everyone to access the resource, you can still use `Condition` to limit access to your resource.

```
AllowSNS2SQSPolicy:
    Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
    Properties:
      Queues: [ !Ref SQSQueue ]
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Id: SQSPolicy
        Statement: 
        - Sid: Allow-SNS-SendMessage    
          Effect: Allow 
          Principal: '*'
          Action:   
          - 'sqs:SendMessage'
          - 'sqs:ReceiveMessage' 
          Resource: !GetAtt [SQSQueue, Arn]
          Condition:
            ArnEquals:
              aws:SourceArn: !GetAtt YourEcsClusterResource.Arn
```

Here is the bit of documentation helped me: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-basic-examples-of-sqs-policies.html

Comment: This worked for me (sorry no code in comments):

Principal: Service: "events.amazonaws.com"

Comment: can we use "sqs.amazonaws.com"?

Answer (score 1):

This should solve it:

```
AllowSNS2SQSPolicy:
  Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
  Properties:
    Queues: [ !Ref SQSQueue ]
    PolicyDocument:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Id: SQSPolicy
      Statement: 
      - Sid: Allow-SNS-SendMessage    
        Effect: Allow 
        Principal:    
          AWS:'arn:aws:ecs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId:}:cluster/foo'
        Action:   
        - 'sqs:SendMessage'
        - 'sqs:ReceiveMessage' 
        Resource: !GetAtt [SQSQueue, Arn]
```

Answer (score 1):

My first stupid error: I wrote

`"Principal": <my ARN>`

instead of

```
"Principal": {
   "AWS": <my ARN>
}
```

Second error, not so stupid: I tried to use lambda arn as principal but had to use the lambda **role** arn instead. So, for the original question, I suggest to use not the ecs arn but the ecs role arn.

Comment: i was using lambda arn, using lambda role arn worked